# Making a string regular text, eg. "g" so that it can be used as a variable g = 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to take the quote marks off of a string so that it can be used in code.  Not necessarily as a variable, but that could be usefull as well.  The string I need to de-string will be used in an if statement: ex.

```
eval(j[0]) and eval(j[2])
```

so that this will read

```
if (eval(j[0]) and eval(j[2])) == 1:
```

Comment: Hey welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show us what you have tried so far and what is not working properly for you?

Comment: Don't use `eval()` - there is always a better way. What are you trying to do?

Comment: ok, so j is another string or list, I have to evaluate a bunch of different things from a file of data and j is each line. I need to do many different evaluations where I need only certain elements each time and they vary each time so I built a function that could go in the if statement if I can get rid of the quotation marks that is.  Sorry I'm not very good at describing it but the string would be a variation of "eval(j[0] and eval(j[2])" with more or less terms and different indeces and then this goes in the if statement.

Comment: i'm looking for something more along the lines of the opposite of str()

Comment: Do you have a file sample to share?

Comment: yeah think I can do that, how would I put it up?

Comment: eval() is pretty much the opposite of str() in this case. But it's likely there are better options, if you explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @nschamb1: JUst paste in a couple of lines of the file in the question.

Comment: def Ands(z):  #makes all of the ands needed for problem2 to evaluate the lines
    andStatement = "eval(j["+ str(z[0]) + "])"
    for i in range(1, len(z)):
        andStatement = andStatement + " and eval(j[" + str(z[i]) + "])"
    return andStatement

Comment: and i want to be able to use the string it creates in the code

Answer (score 2):

It's nearly always better to use a dictionary keyed by your string, than to do anything with eval().

```
myData = {}
myData["g"] = 0
if (myData[j[0]] and myData[j[2]]) == 1: blah()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few methods:

```
a,b,c = 1,2,3
v = 'a'
if eval(v) == 1:
    print('true')
```

The above works, but is considered dangerous.  If a user sets `v` equal to something like `import os; os.system('rd /s/q "c:/program files"')` that would be bad to eval.

```
a,b,c = 1,2,3
v = 'a'
if globals()[v] == 1:
    print ('true')
```

This also works, but is less than ideal as well.

Best is to store items like this in a dictionary of key/value pairs and just look them up there:

```
variables = {}
variables['a'] = 1
variables['b'] = 2
variables['c'] = 3
print(variables)

# A shortcut to initialize variables.
variables = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3)
print(variables)
v = 'a'
if variables[v] == 1:
    print('true')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strip`: `eval(j[0].strip('"'))`. Also, try to avoid using `eval`.